# Combine actor model with RESTful API

Tags: actor, akka.net, actor-model

I’ve been studying the actor model for some time and trying to figure out how to correctly combine it with a RESTful API. I’m struggling how to separate responsibilities of both layers, either by using the ask-pattern or the actor-per-request. With both patterns request-reply semantics are leaking into the actor model, which seems like an anti-pattern. Most messages, initiated by an HTTP-requests, send to an actor require a reply. The receiving actors have multiple conditionals where it needs signals the API it cannot fulfil the request.

Furthermore, what is considered good practice in regard to input validation; should this be implemented as part of the HTTP (for example if field X is a valid email address, if field Y holds an integer). And for complex domain logic, how/should the actor notify the sender when a (pre-)condition fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While request/reply is an anti-pattern in inter-actor communication, nothing stands on your way to use it from outside of an actor system. You can use `Ask` from there and by using combination of `Forward` + `Tell` back to original sender send the reply without necessarily using request/reply model inside of an actor.

When it comes to input validation, ofc the simple validation (field presence, email format etc.) can be easily done on the web framework's level. However more advanced cases (like permission management) will probably make use of actors - at least if your business logic uses them as well.

For complex scenarios - try to think with protocols. Describe set of contracts between actors and/or external services, and use messages to control flow of your logic. It's usually hard to describe that kind of reasoning, but it's usually very easy to draw it with pencil ;)

I.e. you may decide to use some kind of `AuthorizationGate` actor, which given an unathorized request, will validate it: on auth failure it sends back some `RequestFailed` message back to original sender (the asker), on success it could transform that message into `ValidRequest` and send it to actor responsible for handling that message type. Then an actor (which handles only valid requests), processes it, sends `RequestSucceed` or `RequestFailed` back to original sender (remember to either store that sender as message field, or use actorRef.Forward instead of actorRef.Tell so you don't override it).